# Is there a OS library for C++

Tags: python, c++, operating-system, filesystems, c++17

Let's say I want to make a file manager, And I need to fetch the names of all the files in a given path. In python I would do something like: `os.listdir(path)`. So is a c++ library like the OS module.

Comment: Yes. You have [`std::filesystem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c).

Comment: This should be an answer on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
```

for this.

For some older compilers you might need to check if only experimental filesystem is available and use that.

```cpp
#pragma once

#if __has_include(<filesystem>)

#include <filesystem>
namespace filesystem = std::filesystem;

#else

#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace filesystem = std::experimental::filesystem;

#endif
```

Then to iterate over files:

```cpp
   for (auto it : filesystem::directory_iterator("path/to/iterate"))
   {
       // Use it.path
   }

   // Or recursively
   for (auto it : filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("path/to/iterate"))
   {
       // Use it.path
   }
```

Comment: Note that neither `#pragma once` nor `__has_include` is standard C++.

Comment: __has_include is standard since c++17 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include, and #pragma once is not standard, by implemented by most compilers

Comment: Thanks for the correction on `__has_include`. And, yes, `#pragma once` is implemented by many compilers, but there are contexts where it cannot be relied on (for example networks with multiple paths to the same file), which is why it is not standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can import [boost's filesystem libs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) like so:

```cpp
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

Perhaps that works?

Comment: While Boost is a valuable resource, there are standard answers as well, in this case <filesystem>